openapi, redocly-cli: $ref wrong reference path
I use command below to merge many yaml file to one file json:
redocly bundle --dereferenced src/index.yaml --output dist/index.json

A part of file index.yaml:
    responses:
      '200':
        description: "request thành công"
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                data:
                  $ref: "../common/responses.yaml#/field_group_object"  # Pay attention to this line
                code:
                  type: integer
                  example: 200
                message:
                  type: string
                  example: request thành công
      $ref: "../common/responses.yaml#/status"  # Pay attention to this line

After run command. No error, but I check index.json:
    "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "request thành công",
        "content": {
          "application/json": {
            "schema": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "data": {
                  "$ref": "index.yaml#/components/schemas/field_group_object" # Error because index.json is combined to 1 file, it do not reference in other file in outside
                },
                "code": {
                  "type": "integer",
                  "example": 200
                },
                "message": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "example": "request thành công"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      # this is $ref: "../common/responses.yaml#/status". It's work
      "401": {
        "description": "Token is invalid or is expired. Please login again.",
        "content": {

Not error when running but
"$ref": "index.yaml#/components/schemas/field_group_object" can not be used
because index.json is combined to 1 file, it do not reference in other file in outside
Thanks for reading!

share the content of both files.  It will be difficult to explain without this information.

@JeremyFiel I have resolved problem, many thank you
